# write dataframe using to_xml function

Tags: pandas, xml

I have a DataFrame that I want to send to an XML file.

```
      song|title  song|artist song|year
0        Stronger   Kanye West      2007
1     Truth Hurts        Lizzo      2017
2  You're So Vain  Carly Simon      1972
```

I have tried this:

```
df.to_xml(index=False, root_name='top_three', row_name='song',
           attr_cols=['title', 'artist', 'year'], xml_declaration=True,
           pretty_print=True)
```

But am getting this error when I run the code.

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_xml'
```

Sample XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top_three>
    <song>
    <title>Stronger</title>
    <artist>Kanye West</artist>
    <year>2007</year>
    </song>
    <song>
    <title>Truth Hurts</title>
    <artist>Lizzo</artist>
    <year>2017</year>
    </song>
    <song>
    <title>You're So Vain</title>
    <artist>Carly Simon</artist>
    <year>1972</year>
    </song>
</top_three>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

to_xml is New in pandas version 1.3.0.
you probably run a lower pandas version, install pandas >= 1.3.0

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve your answers?